# Bootstrap Panel-Title: Having a title text with ellipsis and buttons on right side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If the text is (too) long, the button is shifted down.
I would like to have:

- the buttons still on the right side and always on the same top-level
- the text be shortened (ellipsis) right before the button

Is this possible?

```css
.panel-heading h3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
With short text it works great!
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                New
            </button>
        </h3>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
But with long text, the button is lower: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                New
            </button>
        </h3>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's possible .. Please add to the question your code showing some effort. If you can an example on bootply is better.

Comment: spending an hour on formatting html-code on stackoverflow-question had no results, so here is the link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jobacca/0qhtgewm/)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you feel like doing it or not, Jobacca; it's a requirement.

Comment: This is pretty difficult to do with pure CSS due to the variable width of the text div. However, it's pretty simple using old school `table` tags.

Comment: You're unable to add your code from your fiddle to your question? That's also a requirement: if you provide a fiddle, you have to include the code in your question because fiddles can go away after some time.

Comment: @Jobacca embedding your code took all of 10 seconds. I really don't know why it would have taken you an hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `pull-left` to your `h3` tags.

```
<h3 class="panel-title pull-left">
```

Set a `width` and `padding-top` to your CSS. The width prevents the `h3` content from taking up the full width of the panel (adjust to your liking), and the `padding-top` pushes it down a bit so it's more inline with your button.

```
.panel-heading h3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 75%;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

Move the button outside of the `h3` tag.

```
<h3 class="panel-title pull-left">With short text it works great!</h3>
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right">New</button>
```

Here's the results of everything in a Code Snippet bellow.

```css
.panel-heading h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 75%;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">
With short text it works great!
            </h3>

    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">New</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">
But with long text, the button is lower: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

        </h3>

    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">New</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
</div>
```